# No Join in Linq

Tags: linq

I have two tables that I have joined in a query like this

```
IQueryable<Auction> closed =
                (from a in CurrentDataSource.Auctions
                 join p in CurrentDataSource.Payments
                     on a.Id equals p.AuctionId
                 where <some condition>
                 select a);
```

What I want really is to say give me all auctions where there **IS NO** join with the Payments table or some condition is true.  I can do this with T-SQL but not sure how to do it with Linq.  Can you help?

Comment: Posting your working sql can help with the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a left outer join and check for payments being null, just like you can in T-SQL.

```
IQueryable<Auction> closed =
                (from a in CurrentDataSource.Auctions
                 join p in CurrentDataSource.Payments
                     on a.Id equals p.AuctionId into temp
                 from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where t == null && <some condition>
                 select a);
```

Comment: doesn't the join condition here give you only matching rows?

Comment: @SachinKainth this is the syntax for a left outer join, and when combined with the `t==null` condition, will give only auctions without associated payments. See the LINQ left outer join documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx